How to solved error when I am using percentages in a matrix
I have the following data source where I have to count by visit date the times that a process has passed through each month in each state, applying the visit date as the main filter for the following example I do it with the month of April.
The following is the data source I use.
City        Location            Name            Visit Date  Status      Enroll Month Enroll Year
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Open        May          2023   
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Progress    May          2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Canceled    May          2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Closed      May          2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Open        April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Progress    April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Canceled    April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Closed      May          2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Open        April        2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Progress    May          2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Canceled    May          2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Closed      June         2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Open        April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Progress    August       2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Canceled    August       2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Closed      August       2023

To count the number of times a process has been in each month based on the date of visit, I use the following measure:
Total Proc. Open = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Open")

The same goes for each of the different Status:
Total Proc. Progress = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Progress")) 
Total Proc. Canceled = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Canceled")) 
Total Proc. Closed = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Closed"))

To make all this data fit the matrix I'm making, I use an additional measure where I make use of a Switch:
Measure Status =
    SWITCH(VALUES(Table1[STATUS]),
    "Open",[Total Proc. Open],
    "Progress",[Total Proc. Progress],
    "Canceled",[Total Proc. Canceled],
    "Closed",[Total Proc. Closed])

So far everything is working correctly for me and the data is displayed correctly as I want in the following matrix:

The error happens when I want to show the percentages of the previous data in a new matrix, i.e. I want them to be displayed as follows:

For the calculation of the percentages in the matrix, I have done something similar to the previous matrix where I use a Switch, the measure is as follows:
Percentage Measure = 
SWITCH(VALUES(Table1[STATUS]), 
"Open","100%",
"Progress",DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Progress"),CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Open")),
"Canceled",DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Canceled"),CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Open")),
"Closed",DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Closed"),CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Open")))

When using the previous measure it only shows me the percentages of the month that I have selected in the filter and does not show me the others, an example below of what is shown is the following:

Are there any changes I need to make to my measure to achieve the goal?

If you want to always show all the month, why do you use a filter? In any case, you can try to use the "Edit interactions" button in the format pane so that the slicer will not filter the desired matrix.
